# Laravel TestCase not sending Authorization headers (JWT Token)

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5, testcase

**Summary**

We are writing unit tests to test the creation and invalidation of JWT tokens and receiving a "The token could not be parsed from the request" error back from a JWTException every time we try to JWTAuth::invalidate the token.

**Description**

Inside our controller, to create a user token, we are passing through the user email address and then returning the JWT token.

Afterwards, we are destroying the token by invalidating it using invalidateToken method and passing through the token by sending an Authorization header.

```
public function invalidateToken()
{
    try {
        JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());
        return Response::json(['status' => 'success'], 200);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return Response::json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()], 401);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly by using Postman as well as PHPStorms Restful client.

When we try to write a test for this method, we are faced with an error response and a "The token could not be parsed from the request" error message.

Our test is as follow:

```
public function testInvalidateToken()
{
    $createUserToken = $this->call('POST', '/token/create', ['email' => 'test@test.com']);
    $user = $this->parseJson($createUserToken);

    $response = $this->call('POST', '/token/invalidate',
        [/* params */], [/* cookies */], [/* files */], ['HTTP_Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$user->token]);

    // var_dump($user->token);
    // die();

    $data = $this->parseJson($response);
    $this->assertEquals($data->status, 'success');
    $this->assertEquals($data->status, '200');
}
```

We are using Laravel 5.1 (which has the cookies as a parameter before the server parameter)

PHP version 5.6.10

PHPUnit 3.7.28

*** EDIT ***
Updated to PHPUnit 4.7.6 and still failing to send through Authorization header.

*** SOLUTION ***
In my controller __construct method, I have these few lines of code that is running and sorted out my issue.

```
if ((\App::environment() == 'testing') && array_key_exists("HTTP_Authorization",  Request::server())) {
    JWTAuth::setRequest(\Route::getCurrentRequest());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We faced a similar issue when writing tests on Laravel 4.2, exceptionally we added this lines when running the application on the testing environment:

```
 // This will only work when unit testing
        if ((\App::environment() == 'testing') && array_key_exists("HTTP_Authorization",  LRequest::server())) {
            $headers['Authorization'] = LRequest::server()["HTTP_Authorization"];
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried the following code in Controller constructor:

```
if (env('APP_ENV') == 'testing' 
        && array_key_exists("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION", request()->server())) {
    JWTAuth::setRequest(\Route::getCurrentRequest());
}
```

Comment: I'm trying your code but \Route::getCurrentRequest() returns null. Any idea why that might be? thx

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to send a token to our API, If header is not working simply append to your URL.
Example:

```
 http://api.mysite.com/me?token={yourtokenhere}
```

So you could do this:

In your TestCase

```
public function signIn($data=['email'=>'youremail@yahoo.com', 'password'=>'password'])
{
    $this->post('/auth/signin', $data);
    $content = json_decode($this->response->getContent());

    $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('token', $content, 'Token does not exists');
    $this->token = $content->token;

    return $this;
 }
```

This will grab and  store a token in $this->token so you can use it to make a request

Then later in your tests

```
public function testResticted()
{
    $this->signIn();
    $this->call('GET', '/restricted/page', ['token'=>$this->token], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = []);
    dump($this->response);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache by default consumes this header. You can fix apache behavior by adding this to your site .conf file:

```
# Workaround apache consuming the header.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```