# Can't include Authorization header with Laravel's unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, jwt, laravel-5

After searching and testing different methods for hours the following seems to be the way to include an authorization header with unit tests inside Laravel 5.2 for jwt-auth:

```
$this->post(route('share.upload'), [
            'type' => 'video'
        ], ['HTTP_Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token])....
```

What I have tried beside that:

- Using `Authorization` instead of `HTTP_Authorization`
- putting `['HTTP_Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]` inside `['headers' => _HERE_ ]`

Also the token is generated correctly and I've used `->dump()` to get the output and the exception is :

```
The token could not be parsed from the request
```

I dumped the headers in a middleware (that's placed before `jwt.auth`) and there's an authorization element: `authorization`

I thought what the heck , maybe it's because of the lower case a!!! 
But then did the same thing with my rest client(which returns a successful response) but it was just the same.

Any ideas? Thaaaanks

P.S: I've also seen this: [Laravel TestCase not sending Authorization headers (JWT Token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31309098/laravel-testcase-not-sending-authorization-headers-jwt-token)

Comment: Just to make sure we all see the code, please include middleware code you are using and tell us version you use (master or develop)?

Comment: The middleware was an ACL implementation of mine. I just added a code like `var_dump($request->headers()->all()); exit();` to see what headers are present. and I'm using the master branch of 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem:

1. In my login method, added a line to save the jwtauth token to a file. But only when `env('APP_DEBUG', false) == true;`
2. Instead of using `$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);` to get the token to test the api, I read the token from the file.
3. Added the file containing the token to `.gitignore` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included your middleware class as I asked, so I can only guess.

First of all you should in your test do something like this:

```
$user = User::find(1); // sample user
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

$this->post(route('share.upload'), [
            'type' => 'video'
        ], ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token]);
```

and in your middleware you need to make sure you don't do simply:

```
JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

but

```
JWTAuth::setRequest($request)->parseToken()->authenticate();
```

if you don't use `setRequest` method, your tests will fail also in case if using for example Postman everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marcin. But I think I've misled you. The middleware that throws the exception, is the default `jwt.auth` middleware that works totally fine everywhere but when testing. The middleware that I mentioned: I just added a line to view the headers and see if the authorization is there.

Comment: Also I just checked the jwtauth middleware, and it contains what you said: `if (! $token = $this->auth->setRequest($request)->getToken())` (duh!)

Comment: The problem is here => `$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);` That's exactly what I'm doing, and if I get a valid token some other way, the exception disappears!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that Apache stripes your Authorization header.
So add the following code to your .htaccess to solve this problem:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

## Alternative

Of course, you can add the token as URL parameter instead of sending as header.

> http://foo.com/page.php?token=YourJWTToken

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response man. But I forgot to mention that unfortunately I've done both these things to no avail.